# In windows form design page shows error

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows forms doesn't show a design page. It shows like:

> The ConnectionString Property has not been Initialized

and

> The variable "controlname" is either undeclared or was never assigned

But the `designer.cs` page contains the variable

```
private Controls.MainControl controlname
```

even though it shows the error.

Give me some idea to solve this.

Comment: Usually this can be fixed by doing Build -> Rebuild and then closing and restarting visual studio

Comment: @EpicKip thanks for your reply. I clean my solution, and rebuild and restart  VS. But the same thing happend again

Comment: Hmm weird, if I find a solution you will see me back

Comment: @Adarsh Ravi I approved your edit. When editing, please also [remove things like "thanks in advance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333).

Comment: @S.L.Barth Sure I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Getting an exception at design-time can cause a lot of trouble.  Of course your control should never need a connection string at design time, that can never come to a good end.  You must disable risky code by wrapping it with `if (!this.DesignTime) { /* etc */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error is *The variable "controlname" is either undeclared or was never assigned* - that means, it exists but no value has been assigned. I don't know your *MainControl* class but if you have an empty constructor you could use this:

```
private Controls.MainCotrol controlname = new Controls.MainControl();
```

Now the variable is declared and this error shouldn't occur. The other error with *The ConnectionString Property has not been Initialized* probably means, that you have the property `ConnectionString` which you're using in another control - therefore you have to assign something (e.g. an empty string) to it:

```
public string ConnectionString {get; set;} = "";
```

But all of this wouldn't happen, if you wouldn't mess with the *designer.cs* class. If you want to change code, do this in the code behind (Press F7 in the designer). But the *designer.cs*  is automatically generated from the designer and therefore shouldn't be manually editted.

If you want to fix the error with `controlname` properly delete all occurences of it from the designer, switch to the design view, open the Toolbox (CTRL + ALT + X), select your control (it should appear there, as long as it's a proper control) and drag it to the form.

As I can't know how you used the `ConnectionString` property I can't give you advise on how to solve this error in an elegant way.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: I got some idea from your answer and i get Design page Thank you.